# How would I check in javascript if any of the divs in my container div got clicked

Tags: javascript, html

Hello I am starting a tic tac toe game and am unsure how to check if any of the elements in my board div got clicked in javascript. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
<div class="board">
        <div class="box" data-index='0'></div>
        <div class="box" data-index='1'></div>
        <div class="box" data-index='2'></div>
        <div class="box" data-index='3'></div>
        <div class="box" data-index='4'></div>
        <div class="box" data-index='5'></div>
        <div class="box" data-index='6'></div>
        <div class="box" data-index='7'></div>
        <div class="box" data-index='8'></div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use an event listener on the outer `div` to listen for a click. Then use the event target to determine which was clicked. To find the index, use `dataset` to grab the `data-index` value.

```js
document.querySelector('.board').addEventListener('click', which);

function which(event) {
  alert(`Index ${event.target.dataset.index} got clicked!`);
}
```

```css
.box {
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  border: 1px solid darkblue;
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="board">
  <div class="box" data-index='0'></div>
  <div class="box" data-index='1'></div>
  <div class="box" data-index='2'></div>
  <div class="box" data-index='3'></div>
  <div class="box" data-index='4'></div>
  <div class="box" data-index='5'></div>
  <div class="box" data-index='6'></div>
  <div class="box" data-index='7'></div>
  <div class="box" data-index='8'></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like what you want is a click event listener: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/click_event

To learn more about thinking about JavaScript in terms of listening for events rather than checking to see if something happened, check out https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events

Answer (score 0):

You can use `onclick="function_name"` with javascript:

```js
function whichDiv(x) {
    console.log(x)
}
```

```html
<div class="board">
    <div class="box" data-index='0' onclick="whichDiv(0)">0</div>
    <div class="box" data-index='1' onclick="whichDiv(1)">1</div>
    <div class="box" data-index='2' onclick="whichDiv(2)">2</div>
    <div class="box" data-index='3' onclick="whichDiv(3)">3</div>
    <div class="box" data-index='4' onclick="whichDiv(4)">4</div>
    <div class="box" data-index='5' onclick="whichDiv(5)">5</div>
    <div class="box" data-index='6' onclick="whichDiv(6)">6</div>
    <div class="box" data-index='7' onclick="whichDiv(7)">7</div>
    <div class="box" data-index='8' onclick="whichDiv(8)">8</div>
</div>
```